# PHP fputcsv outputting double records

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fputcsv

I'm using this fputcsv code:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mash`');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$fp = fopen('testCSV.csv', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
fclose($fp);
```

It outputs the CSV great but there are two columns for each mysql column (so everything is doubled)

could anyone see why that would be?

Comment: If the query fails, you `die`, which ends the program, so there's no point in checking `$result` later on when it can't possibly be false. You also `die` after your loop ending the program before you close the file pointer. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mash`');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$fp = fopen('testCSV.csv', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
fclose($fp);
```

mysql_fetch_array will return a combined array by default, this will return associative array only. Or use MYSQL_NUM for numbered - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. I was experiencing the issue described in this post, and your answer perfectly fixed the issue I was facing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

The second parameter to mysql_fetch_array is the key here. The default is to fetch BOTH the assoc ant int key. You probably want to pass in MYSQL_ASSOC here.

Answer (score 0):

**[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) *returns both a numeric and associative index* by default:**

Quoting the manual (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array of strings that
>   corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. The
>   type of returned array depends on how
>   result_type is defined. **By using
>   MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an
>   array with both associative and number
>   indices.** Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only
>   get associative indices (as
>   mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using
>   MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices
>   (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

**Solution:**

- Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- Or: `mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)`